# How do i resolve these depreciation errors during xcode build?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I've built my podfile using flutter and the following depreciations are shown for android 12. I tried pod install and pod outdated returns all as up to date. There are no build errors and i can deploy the application successfully but i want to resolve these depreciation warnings and semantic issues as well. All ios deployment targets are set to 12.0. tried flutter clean, pod deintegrate.

[image: Depreciations & Semantic Issues]

[image: Depreciations & Semantic Issues]

**pubspec.yaml file packages:**

```
description: A new Flutter project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  intl: 0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  http: ^0.13.4
  rxdart: ^0.27.5
  provider: ^6.0.3
  awesome_dialog: ^2.2.1
  jwt_decoder: 2.0.1
  country_code_picker: 2.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.19.2
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.0
  shimmer: 2.0.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  flutter_staggered_animations: 1.0.0
  file_picker: ^4.6.1
  csv: ^5.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  flutter_downloader: ^1.8.1
  image_downloader: ^0.31.0
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.3+1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**Podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '12.0'


ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: You either need to find different packages that use the replacement functions, get the maintainers of these packages to update their code, submit PRs with updates or ignore the deprecation warnings. Your code will still run, but it isn't using the latest features. For example, iPhones can have multiple carriers now, so the original `subscriberCellularProvider` is deprecated in favour of a function that provides all of the cellular providers. Using the deprecated function you will only get one.

Comment: so until the packages are updated i really have no other choice than to bear with the depreciations or replace the packages it seems. Thank you for the answer @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these warnings usually come from packages you use in your project. If these are only warnings, ignore them because they are out of your control but if there are errors, either report to package author or fix the error yourself by forking the repository.

Comment: thank you. these are just warnings so i will be ignoring it until the packages are upgraded by the author

Answer (score 1):

In xcode open the xcworkspace file. Then in product select clean build folder.. then on the top area you will see a warning symbol. On clicking that the left panel should show an warnings to upgrade package..click on that and a pop up will appear with option to update. All the other warnings during build can be ignored.
[image: preview]

Comment: this i have successfully completed before and resolved. But in the ones i have given in the images. These don't have an update option.